# how to using or condition in find command

Tags: find

Now I want to find file size greater than 25MB and date previous 7 days, how to using or? Now I am writing like this:

```
find /var/lib/docker/ -type f ( -size +25M -or -mtime +7 ) -name *.log
```

but it is not working.

Comment: Your text says "size greater than 25MB AND date previous 7 days" but your `find` command say "size greater than 25MB OR date previous 7 days". Which one is it?  Also, _always mention in what *specific* way things are not working_.  For example: "it finds the wrong files", or "it gives me the error (some error message)".

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that you actually mean OR (your text says AND), your command looks correct apart from that the pattern `*.log` needs to be quoted. The `(` and `)` also needs to be quoted or escaped so that the shell doesn't think it's a subshell:

```
find /var/lib/docker/ -type f \( -size +25M -o -mtime +7 \) -name '*.log'
```

Using `'(' ... ')'` would also work, as would using double quotes.

If you don't quote `*.log`, the shell would try to expand that pattern against all filenames in the current directory before executing `find`.

In the command above, I've opted for using `-o` instead of the non-standard `-or`.

If you care about efficiency, you could rearrange the tests as

```
find /var/lib/docker/ -name '*.log' -type f \( -size +25M -o -mtime +7 \)
```

This means that `find` wouldn't have to use a `stat` call to get the size and timestamps of each file unless their names matches `*.log`.